# custom urls for different files (download + embed)

Tags: php

let's say I have an image `http://.../images/1.jpg` and I don't want people to see this url, instead to let them go to `http://.../view.php?f=aADSdR` or something like this. I also want to know how to do it for downloading like this `http://.../download.php?f=aASfasd`

The same thing has to be done with video mp4 files.

I would be really thankful if somebody could provide some article if known.

Comment: Do you have anyway to link the physical file to the `f=` ID string?

Comment: okay, it can be f=1.jpg and folder will be indicated in php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a `mod_rewrite` rule inside of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^view.php?f=(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download.php?f=(.*)$ images/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

The most simple way I can think of doing this is, storing a hash in a database that will correspond to an image (`view.php?f=HASH`). In the table will be the absolute and web paths of the image, one will be used to display the image in `view.php` i.e. `<img src="{$web_path_from_db}">`, and the absolute path you could use to download the file. [Here is a tutorial to do just that](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-file-download)